# move a stock to another stock exchange

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

if a company is traded in 2 stock exchanges, and my broker allows me to buy the stock in both exchanges, is it possible to buy the stock at 1 exchange and move to the other?
does it matter if the 2 exchanges are in different currencies?

Comment: Why do you want to "move to the other"? The exchange does not "have" your stock, so I think you have a misunderstanding and want to know what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: maybe "moving" is not the right term, but I want to hold my stock in another exchange. the reason for that is because in 1 exchange the tax on dividends is withheld at the source, while in the other I need to declare it myself (so I can effectively postpone the tax by 1 year)

Comment: What exchange withholds tax on dividends?

Comment: When you say "exchange", do you actually mean broker? Exchanges don't hold your stock, they only provide a place to buy or sell it. Your broker might hold your stock for you and then sell it on the exchange when you instruct them to do so.

Comment: @DStanley American exchanges for non US residence - https://ibkr.info/article/46 - "We are required by US tax law, for example, to withhold US taxes on dividends paid by US corporations to foreign persons at a rate of 30%"

Comment: It kind of sounds like you do mean "broker," since Interactive Brokers is a broker, not an exchange. But then again, I don't know what the sentence "my broker allows me to buy the stock in both brokers" would mean, so maybe you do mean "exchange" after all. But in any case, what are the two exchanges that you have in mind?

Comment: It _sounds_ like the broker is required to withhold dividends on stock bought at US exchanges for foreign residents. So it is the broker withholding taxes, but it's because of the US laws, not exchange rules.

Comment: @lev why not just sell your stock on the US exchange and buy it on a foreign exchange (that does not withhold taxes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From piecing together the comments and the links you provided here's how I interpret the situation:

- You bought stock through IB in a US company
- By US law, IB is required to withhold tax on dividends at a 30% rate
- You want to avoid that withholding (and presumably pay the tax when you file).

This is because you own stock in a US company - it's not because of the exchange or the broker.

If instead you bought the stock through a foreign exchange (through some sort of Global Depository Receipt), then you *might* be able to keep the full dividend until you file, but it may depend on the terms of the GDR. You might also be able to use a Contract For Difference that has different dividend regulations.

So you can't just "move exchanges" to avoid this law - the reason the tax is being withheld is because you own stock in a US corporation (regardless of what exchange you bought it on), and the broker has to *legally* withhold the taxes.

Answer (score 1):

An exchange is an organized market for buying and selling  the securities that are listed on it.  You buy such securities via a brokerage firm where your account is located.  You cannot move a stock from one exchange to another whereas you can transfer your securities from one brokerage firm to another.

Interactive Brokers is a brokerage firm not an exchange.  If required, they withhold taxes.  Per your link:

> Information relating to tax obligations is reported as required to the tax authorities within your country of residence as well as other countries if trading products subject to any local withholding requirements.  Unless specifically directed by a taxing authority, IBKR does not withhold taxes on proceeds from security sales. We are required by US tax law, for example, to withhold US taxes on dividends paid by US corporations to foreign persons at a rate of 30%. This rate may be lower if the US has entered into a tax treaty with your country. In addition, investment interest income is not subject to US withholding. All withholdings for non-US persons and most entities will be reported on Form 1042-S at the close of each year.

Answer (score 1):

I've contacted my broker and they informed me that it is possible to move a stock from 1 exchange to the other, and they can do it upon request.

but, as @D Stanley mentioned, it will not change the tax requirements